# SSH tunnel to access dual stack resources in AWS (IPv4 + IPv6)

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, proxy, ipv6, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to setup a Bastion and use it as an SSH proxy to access all my private resources in AWS.

I am having hard time debugging why an SSH tunnel to a specific host with dual stack (IPv4 + IPv6) like RDS/PostgreSQL or EKS fails to immediately connect, it just hangs. I tried to force using only IPv4 or IPv6 using options `-4` and `-6` without success. Verbose logs don't show anything interesting.

SSH tunnel:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/digitalasset-sandbox -L 5432:<db_identifier>.<uid>.<aws_region>.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 <username>@<bastion_ip> -p <port>
```

PostgreSQL interactive terminal:

```
psql 'host=localhost port=5432 ...'
```

One of the potential issue I see is the hostname has a DNS record with both A and AAAA entries:

```
$ nslookup <db_identifier>.<uid>.<aws_region>.rds.amazonaws.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   <db_identifier>.<uid>.<aws_region>.rds.amazonaws.com
Address: <ipv4>
Name:   <db_identifier>.<uid>.<aws_region>.rds.amazonaws.com
Address: <ipv6>
```

```
$ nslookup <id>.<???>.<aws_region>.eks.amazonaws.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   <id>.<???>.<aws_region>.eks.amazonaws.com
Address: <ipv4>
Name:   <id>.<???>.<aws_region>.eks.amazonaws.com
Address: <ipv4>
Name:   <id>.<???>.<aws_region>.eks.amazonaws.com
Address: <ipv6>
Name:   <id>.<???>.<aws_region>.eks.amazonaws.com
Address: <ipv6>
```

A workaround is to use IPv4 only on the DNS resolution by adding an entry manually to `/etc/hosts`:

```
<ipv4> <db_identifier>.<uid>.<aws_region>.rds.amazonaws.com
```

But this is not suitable, it does not work with IPv6 and will break eventually if the DNS record changes.